# ask about diskpart in windows 7 to access file in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, windows, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware 7 as ISO file through Windows 7.
I am having `diskpart` in Windows 7 with a partition of 21GB of IDE disk.

Whatever, I want to ask about disk partition code to access file of Windows 7 from Ubuntu.

So which code can be supposed to be used to access files of Windows 7 of 21GB partition from Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose you'd have to mount windows partition on your ubuntu. You can find in-depth tutorial here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions